# How can I fill missing value with mean of dayofweek and hour data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have some questions about how to fill data with multiindex

I have the example of data like this

```
df :

| ind_Dayofweek | ind_Hour | ind_Min |   Date            |load(kW)|
|---------------|----------|---------|-------------------|--------| 
|      0        |    0     |    0    |1/1/2020 00.00.00  |    2   |
|               |          |    1    |1/1/2020 00.01.00  |    1   |
|               |          |    .    |         .         |    .   |
|               |          |    .    |         .         |    .   |
|               |    1     |    0    |1/1/2020 00.01.00  |   Nan  |
|      .        |    .     |    .    |         .         |    .   |
|      .        |    .     |    .    |         .         |    .   |
|      .        |    .     |    .    |         .         |    .   |
|      5        |    23    |    59   |31/12/2020 23.59.00|   Nan  |
```

and also have table grouped by mean of multiindex and drop the date column

```
df_grouped_by_ind_mean :

    | ind_Dayofweek | ind_Hour | ind_Min |load(kW)|
    |---------------|----------|---------|--------| 
    |      0        |    0     |    0    |    1   |
    |               |          |    1    |    3   |
    |               |          |    .    |    .   |
    |               |          |    .    |    .   |
    |               |    1     |    0    |    4   |
    |      .        |    .     |    .    |    .   |
    |      .        |    .     |    .    |    .   |
    |      .        |    .     |    .    |    .   |
    |      6        |    23    |    59   |    1   |
```

(To make it clear, the missing data in `df` is just an example. There are more missing in my data.)

Multiindex of the data, which is computed by the date column, can be shown as below:

`ind_Dayofweek` is in range of [0-6]

`ind_Hour`  is in range of [0-23]

`ind_Min`  is in range of [0-59]

The data is around 1/1/2020 00.00.00 - 31/12/2020 23.59.00

I want to fill missing load values in `df` with matching multiindex in `df_grouped_by_ind_mean`.

For example : 31/12/2020 23.59.00 load data may be filled with mean of data which [dayofweek,hour,min]  = [5,23,59]

I already use

```
  df_grouped_by_ind_mean = df.groupby([df.ind_Dayofweek, df.ind_Hour, df.ind_Min]).mean()
  df = df.fillna(df_grouped_by_ind_mean)
```

but it doesn't works.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: And also please change data sample with problematic data with expected output, in sample data is no missing (NaN) value.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael ! I'm so sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. I already edited the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: ok, how working below solution?

Comment: @jezrael Can you please check this link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FiQkkGRMovATzE0Acq28vJfJ1WbHA5cJ?usp=sharing to investigate my problem?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry to bother you, but I have no idea to continue my work.

Comment: Can yo ucheck my edited solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need replace mean of all 3 columns is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Date'], sort=False)
mean = df.groupby(['ind_Dayofweek', 'ind_Hour', 'ind_Min'])[cols].transform('mean')
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(mean)
```